# Unzip error "End-of-central-directory signature not found"

Tags: microsoft-word, zip, libreoffice, docx

I have a ZIP file that open in Windown/MS Word, (actually it is a .DOCX file). Opening it with LibreOffice / Mac produces:

```
General Error.
General input/output error.
```

`File` says:

```
../Commission Plan.docx: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

And `unzip` says:

```
Archive:  ../Commission Plan.docx
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of ../Commission Plan.docx or
  ../Commission Plan.docx.zip, and cannot find ../Commission Plan.docx.ZIP, period.
```

How do I open this file?

Comment: "perfectly good" does not seem like an apt description.  Rather, this has the tell-tale of a DOCX file that has been downloaded from a WWW server that generates dynamic content but doesn't serve up DOCX files correctly.

Comment: JdeBP, fair. I have no objective metric for "perfectly good", updated text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this alternate zip process to uncorrupt your file. (Idea based on answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/54904/unzip-error-end-of-central-directory-signature-not-found)

```
mkdir DOCX
cd DOCX
jar xvf ../Commission\ Plan.docx
jar cvf ../Commission\ Plan2.docx *
```

This will decompress and recompress using the superior zip utility build into the java runtime on your system.

Comment: Is this solution working for anyone else too?

Comment: Thanks for asking, yes I did get paid the commission and it was great!

Comment: How does using `jar` differ from using `zip -FF`?

Answer (score 3):

Unzipping with **7z** worked for me:

```
7z x COCR2_100.zip
```

---

Install via APT with `apt install p7zip-full`.